# How to create table and insert data using MySQL and Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL table. I'm able to connect to the database but when trying to insert data it is giving internal server error.

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'test'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def create_table():
    cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
    query = "CREATE TABLE potlala (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name  VARCHAR(40), email VARCHAR(40))"
    query = "INSERT INTO pot13 (id, name, email) VALUES ('2222', 'Maria',  'mariaz@activestate.com')"
    cursor.execute(query)
    return "123"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Run the script from the command line and catch the error, print it and include it here. Also, have you tried using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @john yeah I ran the script from the command line,no error pop up but when I localhost  it gives me internal server error and One thing more when I'm changing   "2222" to '1234' in query section ,it is giving me HTTP 200:OK but not inserting anything into database.

Comment: Encapsulate the block in try catch and catch the error. There will definitely be an output.

Comment: I'm completely  new to this things,Will SQLAlchemy  do the work of CRUD with mysql using python and flask?

Comment: It alleviates the need to write sql queries.  Queries become: dbdefs.potlala.query.filter_by(patella_id = your_variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set `query` to a create table statement, but never execute it before setting it to an insert statement and trying to execute that.  The table doesn't exist, so the insert fails.  Execute the first query first.

```
query = "CREATE TABLE ..."
cursor.execute(query)
query = "INSERT INTO ..."
cursor.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two things that you should do:

1. Execute your queries separately.
2. Commit (or rollback) your changes using the sql connection.

```sql
connection = mysql.get_db()
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "CREATE TABLE potlala (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name  VARCHAR(40), email VARCHAR(40))"
cursor.execute(query)
query = "INSERT INTO pot13 (id, name, email) VALUES ('2222', 'Maria',  'mariaz@activestate.com')"
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: be aware of sql injection here `('2222', 'Maria',  'mariaz@activestate.com')`